# How to prove an that if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ then, $a\cdot \:d=b\cdot \:c$

Tags: solution-verification, fundamental-solution

For example if we simplify $\frac{2+x}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}$ then we get $\left(2+x\right)\cdot \:2=2x\cdot \:1$ (this equation has no solution).

So this means that if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ then, $a\cdot \:d=b\cdot \:c$. How can I prove that?

Comment: Hint: How could you make $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{d}{c}$ look simpler?

Comment: Some people consider this a definition

Comment: Start with $a/b=c/d$. Now multiply both sides by $b$. You get $a=cb/d$. Now multiply both sides by $d$. You get $ad=cb$.

Comment: You are right that the equation has no solution, since multiplying both sides of the original by $2x$ you get $2+x=x$ which is obviously nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

''So this means that if a/b=d/c then, a⋅d=b⋅c. How can I prove that?''

You mean $a/b = c/d$.

Just  multiply the equation both with $b$ and $d$. The equality remains valid and gives $ad=bc$.